# chmod /tmp before Elastic Beanstalk install

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, leveldb

My node.js application fails to install on Elastic Beanstalk with the following error when installing the `leveldown` module:

```
prebuild WARN install EACCES: permission denied, access '/tmp/.npm'
```

How do I set full permission on `/tmp` before deploying a new app version with Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0):

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41616528/769726 You can use .ebextensions and deploy a script that changes the permissions.