# Error: EACCES: permission denied when running `npm install` on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've provisioned a default clean node.js app via Elastic Beanstalk, and have a node.js script trying to run `npm install` inside the project directory (`/var/app/current/deploy-dist`), however, the following permission error is thrown:

```
npm WARN locking Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/.npm/_locks/staging-f212e8d64a01707f.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking  /tmp/.npm/_locks/staging-f212e8d64a01707f.lock failed { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/.npm/_locks/staging-f212e8d64a01707f.lock'
npm WARN locking     at Error (native)
npm WARN locking   errno: -13,
npm WARN locking   code: 'EACCES',
npm WARN locking   syscall: 'open',
npm WARN locking   path: '/tmp/.npm/_locks/staging-f212e8d64a01707f.lock' }
npm WARN deploy-dist No description
npm WARN deploy-dist No repository field.
npm WARN deploy-dist No license field.
npm ERR! Linux 4.4.35-33.55.amzn1.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/bin/node" "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/bin/npm" "install"
npm ERR! node v6.9.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.8
npm ERR! path /tmp/.npm/_locks/staging-f212e8d64a01707f.lock
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall open

npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/.npm/_locks/staging-f212e8d64a01707f.lock'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/tmp/.npm/_locks/staging-f212e8d64a01707f.lock'
npm ERR!     at Error (native)
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'open',
npm ERR!   path: '/tmp/.npm/_locks/staging-f212e8d64a01707f.lock' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/app/current/deploy-dist/npm-debug.log
```

The `package.json` is just a:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^1.3.3"
  }
}
```

Running `npm install` with sudo obviously works, but is preferred to be avoided as a solution.

Setting `NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX` to a directory at `~` as per [`npm` docs suggestion](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions) didn't work either, and the problem persists.

I suspect the problem lies in incorrect permissions for `/tmp/.npm`, which are

```
drwxr-xr-x 114 root root 4.0K Dec 27 17:04 .npm
```

This is confusing, as I expected a simple `npm install` to work out of the box.

**UPDATE:** Should not that the project directory already contains a `node_modules` folder, but even removing it and running `npm install` doesn't fix it.

Comment: Someone seems to be having the exact same issue on AWS forum as well right now: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=758699&tstart=0

Comment: How did you run the "npm install" with sudo in this Elastic Beanstalk instance? This is not the way, but I would be able to test my App with this temporary workaround.

Comment: @sergi `sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/bin/node /opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v6.9.1-linux-x64/bin/npm install`

Comment: could you please tell me, are you using github or bitBucket?

Comment: @DinuNicolae neither, a direct upload deploy.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had this problem! You can use [ebextensions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to create a [post-deploy script](http://junkheap.net/blog/2013/05/20/elastic-beanstalk-post-deployment-scripts/) that changes the permissions of the `tmp/npm/.locks` folder.

In your node.js project, create a `.ebextensions` folder if you haven't got one already. Then, add a new config file, e.g. `00_create_postdeploy_script.config`, with the following yaml:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/99_fix_node_permissions.sh":
    mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      #!/usr/bin/env bash
      chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.npm/_locks/
```

When you deploy, this will create a script in `/opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post` called `99_fix_node_permissions.sh`, which looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.npm/_locks/
```

Because it's in that `post` folder, it will be run automatically after your app has deployed -- and hence change the permissions as required.

**EDIT:** If you're having trouble with the permissions of the *whole* `.npm` folder, then you should change the last line of the config file to:

```
chown -R nodejs:nodejs /tmp/.npm/
```

Comment: corrected your answer slightly to fully resolve the issue (chwon `/tmp/.npm` instead of just `/tmp/.npm/_locks`)

Comment: I'm not sure how suggested edits work on here, but I've updated the answer!

Comment: I have noticed a very strange thing. I had this problem only with bit bucket, with github the permissions were fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem in past and in my case cleaning the cache fixed my issue.
Please try this

```
npm cache clean
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Didn't fix it unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

The following command will fix the issue. it worked for me.

```
sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/user/.npm"
```